# Searching one array then get the corresponding data from another array

Tags: c#, arrays, string, search

How can I search from user input the data from one array and get the corresponding data from other arrays? For example, the user wants the get the information by searching their name which has an id number in another array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Linq for this situation.

```
 public class Person
 {
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public int Id { get; set; }
 }


 IEnumerable<string> names = data.Where(x => input.Any(y => y.Id == x.Id)).Select(x => x.Name);
```